# OnItemDataBound don't fires on nested Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a nested Repeater in ItemTemplate of another Repeater.
i add a OnItemDataBound function to the repeater but the code dont execute

the aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptComponents" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptComponents_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span2">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptComponentsImages" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptComponentsImages_ItemDataBound">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul class="bxslider">
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <img src="<%# Eval("CKCI_File")%>" /></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <li runat="server" id="liNoData" visible="false">
                                    <img src="http://placehold.it/132&text=No image" alt=""></li>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <%# Eval("CKC_Title") %>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

the code

```
protected void rptComponents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            ClutchKitComponent rd = (ClutchKitComponent)e.Item.DataItem;

            List<ClutchComponentImage> kitComponentImages = (List<ClutchComponentImage>)rd.images;

            Repeater rt = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptComponentsImages");
            rt.DataSource = kitComponentImages;
            rt.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected void rptComponentsImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rt = (Repeater)sender;
        if (rt.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                e.Item.FindControl("liNoData").Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

the second function don't execute

Comment: Does the outer repeater's `ItemDataBound` execute? Have you set breakpoints?

Comment: The Outer ItemDataBound is fired, i have set breakpoint but it's dont get to them.

Comment: Are you sure there are any items in your DataSource for rptComponentsImages?

Comment: there aren't, i want to show no data label

Comment: If there are no items to bind, you won't get an OnItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had a null on one of the Lists so it's throw an ex that i didn't catch. 
the OnItemDataBound is fired even where is no data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ItemDataBound event for repeater which is inside?
And did you try to add that event in ItemCreated or first ItemDataBound event?

```
rt.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rt_ItemDataBound);
```

Check this link for nested repeaters. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20230/Nesting-Data-bound-Repeater-Controls-in-ASP-Net